# Eclipse plug-in: navigation between Java source code editor and the view created by my plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, navigation

I wanted to implement a similar navigation for my Eclipse plug-in as what's provided in, for example,  the "Outline" view -- when I click on the element (a class, a variable etc) listed in the "Outline" view, the cursor jumps to the corresponding location of that element in the source code editor.

I am not even sure what keywords to search for the solution. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Are you writing the editor or is this the existing Java editor you want to use?

Comment: The existing Java editor. I wanted to click on something in the view that my plug-in generated, and the cursor in the Java editor jumps to a particular line.